# Defining an orthogonal transform from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Explain why a general orthogonal transform ψ: $\mathbb{R}^4$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}^4$ with positive determinant is written as a composition of at most four simple rotations.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem, it was never talked about in class and is an extra credit assignment. There are general matrix representations of orthogonal transforms from R2 to R2 and R3 to R3 though. At first I thought that it had something to do with showing that X^2=XYXY=XXYY and showing that YY is the identity matrix so X^2=XX, but am very uncertain.